# JavaScript Dividing Array Values by an Int

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, division

I can't explain where the error is occurring here but the basic division I am attempting using array values is resulting in outrageously large numbers in the tens of thousands.

Inside of a for loop "for (var i = 0; i < 6; i ++)" I have the follow code"

```
var av1 = (stud[i][0][0] + stud[i][0][1] + stud[i][0][2])/3;
```

For clarity, there is a failure on every iteration of this loop. The initial values are as follows:

```
stud[0][0][0] = '77';
stud[0][0][1] = '81';
stud[0][0][2] = '85';
```

So I would expect an 81, plain and simple. However, the output it is coming up with is 259395. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Convert to parseInt(stud[i][0][0]) + parseInt(stud[i][0][1]) etc.  You get 259395 because that's 778185/3, the result of string concatening the values.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :) I get mixed up in JavaScript because you don't define variable types... and it apparently thought I was making a string >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array values are strings, not integers. As such, your addition is creating a value of 778185. After being type coerced to an integer and divided by 3, you get exactly 259395. You'll need to make sure your integers are stored as integers.